# How to get ID of a row in SQLite?

Tags: android, json, sqlite, row

I have a notes app that is paired width a MySql server. When I want to load notes from the server I get JSONArray width serverId(sid), title, and description of the note. Then I check if serverId(sid) exists in the local SQLite database. If sid exists I want to just update the note width new title and description from the server, but to update the note I need the Sqlite database id of the row and I don't know how to get it. Any ideas? I'm a kinda newbie so I'm glad for any advice.

```
   public void loadServerNotes(String title, String des, String sid){
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       Cursor cursor = null;

       // Here I'm checking if the server id exists in my SQLite database
       String findIfServerIdExist = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COLUMN_SID + " = " + sid + ";";
         
       cursor= db.rawQuery(findIfServerIdExist,null);
      
       // If server id already exists in my SQLite database I want to update the note with the server title and description
// if the server id doesn't exist I create a new note with the server title and description

       boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
       if (exists){

        updateNote(**Id that i need to find**, title, des, Api.NAME_SYNCED_WITH_SERVER, sid);
       }else {
           createNote(title, des,  Api.NAME_SYNCED_WITH_SERVER, sid);
       }
       cursor.close();

   }
```

My SQLite Column's example:

COLUMN_ID / COLUMN_TITLE / COLUMN_DES / COLUMN_STATUS / COLUMN_SID

Answer (score 0):

Answer : I figured out how to do it and its kinda simple here is the code :

```
if (exists){
       if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
           int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(SqliteDatabaseNotes.COLUMN_ID);
            int id = cursor.getInt(index);
            String stid = Integer.toString(id);
           updateNote(stid,title, des, Api.NAME_SYNCED_WITH_SERVER, sid);

       }
```